# pandas list of dicts dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have turned a list of dicts into a dataframe using this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
res_df = pd.DataFrame(d)
res_df.head()
```

Pandas did not interpret the format successfully, I'm guessing bc there were no quotes around the keys of the dict. It looked like this:

**[{location:'playroom',state:'NY',zip:10011},{..}]**

As a workaround, I stripped out "'","{}", and "[]", to make the file standard csv. However, when I call the *names* argument from pd.read_csv, I have two issues: 1 - the names columns are blank, and 2 - I end up with a dataframe that is 1 row with thousands of columns. res_df.transpose() did not work.

If my csv has no header row, and *assuming it has the same number of fields for each record*, why is it that I can't give pandas my column names, and create new dataframe rows based on these arguments/instructions?

What is the quicker/better way to do this?

*Update: here is a snippet of the csv file:

```
websitedotcomcom/,Jim,jim@testdotcom,777-444-5555,Long City, NY,1,http://document-url,,another_field,,,true,12 Feb 2015 (18:17),http://website.com/,Jim,jim@test.com,777-444-5555,Long City, NY,1,http://document-url,,another_field,,,true,12 Feb 2015 (18:17)
```

Comment: you don't need to construct another dataframe, just the **read_csv** will return you the dataframe

Comment: sure, but there's no difference between the two. I still need an output the has more than one row, and there's still an issue with a blank header row.. any suggestions there?

Comment: Can you give an example of the first five lines in the file?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like JSON rather than CSV. You should use pandas [`read_json` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html).

```
df = pd.read_json('/path/to/file.json')
```

Note: that it *is* sensitive to valid json, say you may have to do some string manipulation (e.g. replacing `'` with `"`).

Comment: this is not json, it is a list of dicts.. I'm looking for a way to transform 1 long row into a certain number of fields, so that each field has the same number of columns.. seems like this should be simple, and i've used pandas to create dataframes from lists of dicts hundreds of times w/o encountering this issue until now..